# Python regex removing word with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Python and I want to remove and replace the `({ / / })` with space, the sample below

The original sentence:

```
NULL ({ / / }) Regina ({ 4 p1 p2 / / }) Shueller ({ 5 p1 p2 / / }) works ({ / / }) for ({ / / }) Italy ({ 14 / / }) 's ({ 15 / / }) La ({ 16 / / }) Repubblica ({ 17 / / }) newspaper ({ 18 / / }) . ({ 38 / / })
```

Transform to this:

```
Regina Shueller works for Italy 's La Repubblica newspaper.
```

I've tried this code but that was not what I expected

```
Sentence = re.sub(r'[({ / / })]',' ', sentence)
```

Comment: The best I came up with is [`r'\s*(?:\(\{[^/]*/\s*/\s*}\)|NULL)\s*'`](https://regex101.com/r/nJ4yY8/1) (to be replaced with space). But the space between the last word and the `.` cannot be removed like this. And the value must be trimmed from spaces.

Comment: Your transformed string does not match what you say you want

Comment: Try [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wF4nS6/2) with [Python regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (pattern uses backreference `(?1)`). Or with `re` [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/tC1sJ0/1): `\({[^}]*}\)|NULL|\s+(?!\w)` and trim leading space.

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew for your answer, that regex works well.

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
r'\s*(?:\(\{[^/]*/\s*/\s*}\)|NULL)\s*'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ4yY8/1)

**Regex explanation**:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\(\{[^/]*/\s*/\s*}\)|NULL)` - two alternatives, `NULL` or `\(\{[^/]*/\s*/\s*}\)` matching...

  - `\(` - opening round bracket
  - `\{` - opening brace
  - `[^/]*` - zero or more characters other than `/`
  - `/` - a literal `/`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `/\s*` - ibid.
  - `}` - a closing brace
  - `\)` - a closing round bracket
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

Note that the spaces in between words and punctuation should be handled separately.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/o8CxY6):

```
import re
p = r'\s*(?:\(\{[^/]*/\s*/\s*}\)|NULL)\s*'
test_str = "NULL ({ / / }) Regina ({ 4 p1 p2 / / }) Shueller ({ 5 p1 p2 / / }) works ({ / / }) for ({ / / }) Italy ({ 14 / / }) 's ({ 15 / / }) La ({ 16 / / }) Repubblica ({ 17 / / }) newspaper ({ 18 / / }) . ({ 38 / / })"
result = re.sub(p, " ", test_str)
print(result.strip())
# => Regina Shueller works for Italy 's La Repubblica newspaper .
```

Comment: As a bonus :), try removing the space before non-opening punctuation and symbols with `re.sub(r"\s+([~\`!@#$%^&*)_+=}\]\\|;:.>,-])", r"\1", result.strip())`

Comment: I can't see a -1 here, so.. +1

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried: `r'[({ / / })]'` means:

> Match any single character that is one of `(`, `{`, , `/`, `}`, or `)`

The key to this is understanding the [regular expression language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).  Each of those characters has a special meaning in that language.

A pattern such as `r' \({ [^/]*/ / }\) '` would match each of the different sections in your example.

Comment: That's right! I should have to learn the regular expression deeply. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this:

```
r'(\([^(]*\))'
```

With <kbd>[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS3sV5/1)</kbd>

Comment: I think this regex is rather unsafe for this task.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well... It fits the need, given the provided input. I've simplified it as far as I could, which might be bad if the input provided doesn't reflect the reality.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same you could try keeping alpha's after stripping punctuation:

```
from string import punctuation
print(" ".join([w for w in s.split() if w.strip(punctuation).isalpha()]))
```

Or using a regex:

```
print(re.sub(r'\({.*?}\)',"",s))
```

You are removing everything that has `({})` regardless of what is inside in your expected output.

Comment: The lazy dot matching regex [may play a bad joke on you](https://regex101.com/r/dQ4zT0/1). Do not use lazy dot matching where you do not have to.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I do need it, I meant to remove the / / from the pattern as it is not what the OP i looking to match based on their expected output. What is inside is irrelevant